# scp multiple files in a shell script

Tags: shell

I have a list of directory names.

I want to scp into a remote machine, go into each of my directory names and copy a file back to my local computer.

I so far have:

```
while read line
    do
        scp remote_machine:/home/$line/$line.dat ./local
    done < file_with_directory_names.txt
```

I have authorisation keys set up so that I don't have to enter the password each time - but this method does login to the remote machine for every file it transfers. I imagine that there is a much better way than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify multiple files in a single `scp` argument by separating them with spaces; you just need to make sure it's one argument to `scp` itself.  This should work in your case:

```
scp "remote_machine:$(
    sed 's,.*,/home/&/&.dat,' file_with_directory_names.txt | xargs)" ./local
```

The `sed` command sticks the `/home/` prefix and *name*`.dat` suffix on each line; the `xargs` outputs all the resulting pathnames on a single line separated by spaces.  Plug that all into the source argument after the `remote_machine:` part, all inside double quotes so it's still a single argument to `scp`, and you're good to go.